# How to connect mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps with reduxForm

Tags: redux-form

I am trying to use redux-form. I am following the example from the official document.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Example extends Component {
    // ...
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  => ({
    // ...
});

Example = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Example);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'example' // a unique name for this form
})(Example);
```

This returns Syntax error: "Example" is read-only. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what the error is here. I am using redux-form@7.2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here an example. You need to use function connect then function reduxForm

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = () => ({});

const mapToProps = {};

const mapToForm = {
  form: 'example'
};

class Example extends Component {
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapToProps)(
  reduxForm(mapToForm)(
    Example
  )
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I usually create a separate js to map the state and props. Please see an example below:

**index.js**

```
import Example from './Example'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function mapStateToProp (state) {
  return {
    anything: get(state, 'anything', {})
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProp = dispatch => ({
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProp,
  mapDispatchToProp
)(Example)
```